# Create ViewModel in order to combine 2 models linked

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel

As a newbie with ASP.NET MVC pattern, I'm trying to create a small web application in order to practice knowledge learned through some tutorials.

I have some obscure things about `Model` and `ViewModel`. I understand that Model defined only the table structure whereas ViewModel defined the logic for data, How to handle data... Furthermore, ViewModel is used when I want to display more than one model into my View.
Well, it's very theoretical and I'm trying to develop this with my application.

**My application:**

This application lets to handle `projects` and `people`. I can create a new project object containing some properties: project name, project location, ... and add a list of people who will work on this specific project.

Then, in the other side, I have a simple people table with properties like : Firstname, Lastname and function.

When I create a new project, I would like to select one or multiple people in order to attach them to the project.

**My class People:**

I created a simple class which looks like this:

```
public class People
{
    public int PeopleID{ get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Job{ get; set; }
}
```

I removed `Annotations` in order to see clearer my class.
I created the CRUD associated and it works fine.

**My class Project:**

In this class, I define properties from project object and I would like add a list of people collaborating on the project.

I have:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName{ get; set; }
    public string ProjectLocation{ get; set; }
    public List<People> ListOfPeople { get; set; }
}
```

If I understand, now I have to create a ViewModel in order to create my Project object with information from Project and People classes ?

**My class ProjectPeopleVM:**

This class is identical as Project class ?
So I have:

```
public class ProjectPeopleVM
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName{ get; set; }
    public string ProjectLocation{ get; set; }
    public List<People> ListOfPeople { get; set; }
}
```

Is it right ? I have some doubts about this.

If I want to create a controller class which let to Create a new object Project, I have to fill the ListOfPeople by using EF ? Something like `db.People.ToList()` ?

```
public class ProjectsController : Controller
{
    private MyAppContext db = new MyAppContext();
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var people_list = db.People.ToList();
        var project = new ProjectPeopleVM 
        {
            ListOfPeople = people_list;
            // What I need to add here ? Data to populate ListOfPeople come from people_list variable
        }
        return View(project);
    }
```

I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary that you create a duplicate of your class just to see the information but it seems that in your code, you might need to because;

I noticed that in your Project Model, you didn't use `public virtual List<People>` or the virtual keyword, **which is used for "lazy loading".** When an existing project is taken from the db context, if you have the virtual keyword on your property, then it would automatically load the associated object. On the other hand, if you don't have it, then you will need to manually assign the list. Using lazy loading might have a little effect on the performance but with this you can view the properties of your child class immediately.

If your list has virtual property,

```
public class Project
{
   public int ProjectID { get; set; }
   public string ProjectName{ get; set; }
   public string ProjectLocation{ get; set; }
   public virtual List<People> ListOfPeople { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller or view, you could navigate to the properties of the objects in that list;

```
// this will give the first name of the first person on the first project
db.Project.FirstOrDefault().ListOfPeople.FirstOrDefault().FirstName;
```

For your create action in your controller, since it's a new Project, it doesn't have any People in it. Hence you will need to manually populate that list. To populate it, since you only need specific people, I suggest to use a checkbox or multiple input fields (aided with javascript).

The ListOfPeople can be populated by having a form element;

```
<input name="ListOfPeople[1].PeopleId" value="1"/>
<input name="ListOfPeople[1].FirstName" value="Mark"/>
<input name="ListOfPeople[1].LastName" value="Jacob"/>

<input name="ListOfPeople[1].PeopleId" value="2"/>
<input name="ListOfPeople[2].FirstName" value="Red"/>
<input name="ListOfPeople[2].LastName" value="Wandersee"/>
```

When you submit the form, the values will be bound to the Project model's ListOfPeople. Then that's the time you will need to loop through it and create a ProjectPerson (junction) record which determines where this person belongs to.

```
foreach(var i in model.ListOfPeople){
   ProjectPerson pp = new ProjectPerson();
   ... // do property assignment
   db.ProjectPerson.add(pp);
}
```

Comment: It's a very good answer, I understand more things now thanks to you. I just have question about populating my List. If I want to populate this this in my Create method, I have to use EF and not to hard write data right ? I will look on checkboxes, but firstly I have to add the list of people stored in class People into this list.

Comment: You're welcome. Do you have a separate controller for People? If you don't, then in your Create Project method, you need to use EF to manually create the People first then add them to ProjectPerson .

Comment: Yes I have a separate controller for People. One controller for People with CRUD methods and another one for Project. So I would like in my Create() method from ProjectController, populate the property ListOfPeople through EF.

Answer (score 1):

your view models should be used to map a combination of data drawn from the db. i.e.

```
public class Project
    {
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName{ get; set; }
        public string ProjectLocation{ get; set; }
        public  IColleciton<People> ListOfPeople { get; set; }
    }

public class People
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public virtual Project project { get;set; }
    }
```

this will allow relational retrieval from EF

viewModel should be used when you need a combination of this data without relationship i.e.

```
public class Project
    {
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName{ get; set; }
        public string ProjectLocation{ get; set; }

    }

public class People
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }

    }

public class ProjectVm 
{

        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName{ get; set; }
        public string ProjectLocation{ get; set; }
        public  ICollection<People> ListOfPeople { get; set; }
}
```

you can use a tool such as automapper to set up the mapping between objects which will generate custom model inside controller.

see this article: http://bengtbe.com/blog/2009/04/14/using-automapper-to-map-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc/

and DB Relationships

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/conventions/built-in

Comment: Ok I understand ! So in my case, it should be better to use models with relationship between both classes or create separate classes and make the relationship through ViewModel ?

Comment: well it depends on what your trying to do. Your models should reflect your DB tables exactly. view models are for representing Model data on the view(front end) and dont want to change your models